# JSTL drop down list

Tags: jstl

I have a problem on the front end. No matter what year I chose from the drop down list, the selected year is somehow set to 2015. Any guess how to fix this? Spent nearly 2h staring at this code and I really have no idea at this point.

```
    <div id="tabs-4">
    <div class="input-container" style="padding: 0;">
        <div class="input">
            <div class="controls" style="float: left;">
                <form name="week" id="weekForm" action="${rootContext}/kpi/weekly" method="GET" >
                    <div>
                        Year:<br> <select name="year" id="weeklyYearForm">
                            <c:forEach var="i" begin="2012" end="2020">
                                <option value="<c:out value="${i}"/>"
                                    ${i == yearForWeek ? 'selected' : ''}>
                                    <c:out value="${i}" />
                                </option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Week:<br> <select name="week" id="weeklyWeekForm">
                            <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="53">
                                <option value="<c:out value="${i}"/>"
                                    ${i == weekForWeek ? 'selected' : ''}>
                                    <c:out value="${i}" />
                                </option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" id="runWeekly" value="Run"
                            class="genericSubmitButton" onclick="" name="action">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="controls" style="float: right">

                <form name="week" action="${rootContext}/kpi/recalculateWeek" method="GET" id="recalculateWeekForm">
                    <input type="text" name="year" value="${yearForWeek}">
                    <input type="text" name="week" value="${weekForWeek}"> <input
                        type="submit" id="Recalc" value="Recalculate KPI"
                        class="genericSubmitButton" onclick="">
                </form>

                <form name="week" action="${rootContext}/kpi/downloadKpiByWeek" method="GET">
                    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="${yearForWeek}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="week" value="${weekForWeek}"> <input
                        type="submit" id="OK" value="Export" class="genericSubmitButton"
                        onclick="">
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dataContainerForAjaxWeekly">
    <%@ include file="kpireporttable.jsp"%>
        <!-- This will be updated automatically with Ajax -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that an external JavaScript file was controlling the behavior of the drop menu for 'year selection' and it was missing the method that was controlling the selection. The below Js method fixed my problem.

```
$('#weeklyYearForm').change(function() {
    selectedyear = $("#weeklyYearForm option:selected").val();
    $('input[name=year]').val(selectedyear);
});
```